# If I enable onBoard VGA port will it mess things up on video card?

Tags: windows-7, display, bios

I have PCI Video card it has 2 HDMI and some other port. Total 3 port but only allows 2 monitors display.

I was wondering if I enable built in VGA on mother board will it mess up my video card display?
meaning will it also work or only VGA on mother board will work?

I am doing this so I can have 3 monitors instead of 2.

[http://www.ehow.com/how_7345928_enable-onboard-vga-chip-bios.html](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/news/amd_set_launch_ati_hd_4600_its_answer_nvdia_geforce_9500_series_september_10)

Screenshot for Bios

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't cause damage if that's what you're asking. Your motherboard may support using both, or may not. If you enable it and only the onboard works, then you know your MB only supports one at a time. At that point you could undo your changes.

If you're desperate to get three monitors but don't want to invest in a motherboard upgrade, you could get a USB video adapter for less than $40 on Newegg.

Comment: I can't add hardware to it. I don't own this PC. I can't modify hardware

Comment: Most modern boards should support both onboard VGA + the PCI card. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: How can I enable my VGA Port? I am not able to see it in Bios either.

Comment: Every BIOS is different on every PC. If you can link a screenshot, I might be able to point you in the right direction, but if there is nothing related to video in any of the menus, I would say your motherboard doesn't support running both.

Comment: I updated photos plz refresh page.

Comment: In the on-board devices or PCI devices page, are there options related to the primary video adapter? Can I get a screenshot of those menus?

Comment: Please Check updated photos, (Last 3 photos)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like you have the option to enable both. I searched the issue with HPs and majority of forums say that users don't have the option, and they show the same thing you're seeing. Unfortunately I'd say you're unable to use both.

Comment: :( that really sucks, thanks a lot for your help. really.